# Detect UIWebView links without click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I was wondering is there any possible way to detect a link in `UIWebView` without click on  urls ? for example if page has `PDF` file automatically get its link. I know with webview's delegate I can detect clicked urls like this :

```
  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {

        if navigationType == .linkClicked
        {
            print(request.url?.absoluteString)
        }
        return true
    }
```

but is there any possible way to detect links without click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSDataDetector for link types `NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link`. You just need to download your url data and get all the link matches from it:

```
extension String {
    var detectURLs: [URL] {
        return (try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue))?
            .matches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count))
            .compactMap{ $0.url } ?? []
    }
}
extension Data {
    var string: String { return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" }
}
```

Playground Testing:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// add the extensions above here

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/downloads/")!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    let pdfs = data.string.detectURLs.filter{$0.pathExtension.lowercased() == "pdf"}

    print(pdfs)  // print(urls)  // "[http://www.sample-videos.com/pdf/Sample-pdf-5mb.pdf]\n"
}.resume()
```

Comment: This is great ! but is there any possible way to filter links based on a file ? for example I need link which contains `.pdf`

Comment: I will store all urls to a an Array and then filter array if contains `pdf` , Is this this OK ?

Comment: It's ok I am looking for direct links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146182/discussion-between-mc-lover-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSXMLParser` to parse the `HTML body` of the `UIWebView` and look for `a` tags, and get their `href` parameter which contains the url.