# How to find the frame of substring inside a UILabel in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel which contains some string as

> "I agree to below Terms & Condistions"

.

Now on click of "Terms & conditions" i want to get it's frame so that i can add a button on that position at run time to detect the touch on particular word. By i am not sure how can i detect ?

Comment: traverse your label text and check your substring , when you found it then omit that substring for your label text and create new button and add in ui lable and set constraint on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19332283/1891327

Answer (score 1):

We can't make a uilabel accessible properties as you want in your case we can make use of TextView here for such property

my class :

```
import UIKit

class TextViewVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    let termsAndConditionsURL = "termsandconditions"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let str = "I agree to below Terms & Condistions"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
        let foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "Terms & Condistions")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: foundRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: foundRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: termsAndConditionsURL, range: foundRange)

        textView.attributedText = attributedString

    }
}

extension TextViewVC : UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
    {
        if (URL.absoluteString == termsAndConditionsURL)
        {
            print("Need an action here")
        }
        else {
            print("No")
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

My storyBoard for creating a textView :

[image]

Simulator output

[image]

Console Output

[image]

Comment: NSAttributedStringKey keyword is redundant.  `attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: foundRange)`. The same applies for `.underlineStyle` and `.link`. Btw no need to include `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your code.

Comment: I haven't tested but `rawValue` might not be necessary also. It compiles without it I just don't know if it would run properly as I have seen cases where it doesn't.

Comment: it is running properly in my case as I checked I just created a sample file to check do this code is woking or not so I didn't removed didReceiveMemoryWarning that came up by default if you want I can share a link to my code file

Comment: I mean NSAttributedStringKey is inferred by the compiler so you don't need to add it there. If you don't add any code in your didReceiveMemoryWarning method it is ok to remove it also.

Comment: The only think you should test is if  `attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle, range: foundRange)` works (without the .rawValue)

Comment: Yes Thats why I told you to test it before removing it. I don't know why it doesn't work but it should work. You should consider reporting a bug to Apple